# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in xml builder template

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple method to generate a XML-sitemap with a builder-Template. Everything works fine until migration from rails 3 to rails 4 (now Rails 4.2.5.1, Ruby 2.3.0)

**articles_controller.rb**

```
def sitemap
@other_routes = ["page1","page2","page3"]

respond_to do |format|
format.xml { render :xml, layout: false }
end
```

**sitemap.xml.builder**

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => "1.0"
xml.urlset "xmlns" => "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" do

xml.url do
xml.loc ("http://#{request.host_with_port}")
xml.changefreq("daily")
xml.priority 1.0
end

@other_routes.each do
xml.url 
{
xml.loc ("http://{request.host_with_port}/{routes.to_s}")
xml.changefreq("daily")
xml.priority 0.6
}
end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get "/sitemap.xml" => "articles#sitemap", 
:defaults => { :format =>   'xml' }
```

Now i get the following error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

@other_routes.each do
xml.url {
xml.loc ("http://{request.host_with_port}/{routes.to_s}")
xml.changefreq("daily")
```

It looks like the @other_routes does not get propagated to the template?

Comment: Check this link https://richonrails.com/articles/outputting-xml-using-ruby-on-rails, I hope this will help.

Comment: Okay, it was my mistake. I had an "end" at the wrong position. Now it works